Extract entities with Gemini
I'm doing a chat with Gemini, and its already working, but i want to extract structured data from the prompts to save to firestore.
typedef Seizure = (
int id, {
String type,
String? duration,
});

extension on Seizure {
  Map<String, Object?> toJson() {
    return {
      'id': $1,
      'type': type,
      'duration': duration,

    };
  }
}

class ChatPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const ChatPage({super.key});

  @override
  State<ChatPage> createState() => _ChatPageState();
}

class _ChatPageState extends State<ChatPage> {
  // Text controller stores the data of the TextField it's assigned to
  TextEditingController messageController = TextEditingController();

  late final model = GenerativeModel(
    model: 'gemini-pro',
    apiKey: GEMINI_API_KEY,
    requestOptions: const RequestOptions(apiVersion: 'v1beta'),
    tools: [
      Tool(
        functionDeclarations: <FunctionDeclaration>[
          FunctionDeclaration(
            'add_seizure',
            'Add a new seizure to the list',
            Schema(
              SchemaType.object,
              properties: {
                'type': Schema(
                  SchemaType.string,
                ),
                'duration': Schema(
                  SchemaType.string,
                  nullable: true,
                ),
              },
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ],
  );

  final extractContent = FunctionDeclaration(
      'extract_content',
      'Return the seizures reported',
      Schema(SchemaType.object,
          properties: {
        'type': Schema(SchemaType.string,
            description: 'A focal (only sensations) or generalized (falls or conscious loss) seizure'),
        'duration': Schema(SchemaType.string,
            description: 'How long the seizure lasted'),
      },
      )
  );

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Aura'), // Try changing AppBar title
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment:
          MainAxisAlignment.center, // Vertically centered column
          children: [
            // Expanded takes up the whole space
            Expanded(

              child: StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>>(
                stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
                    .collection('aura_chat')
                    .orderBy('timestamp', descending: true)
                    .snapshots(),
                builder: (context, snapshot) {
                  // Show error text on error
                  if (snapshot.hasError) {
                    return Center(child: Text('$snapshot.error'));
                  } else if (!snapshot.hasData) {
                    // Show circular loading indicator while loading
                    return const Center(
                      child: SizedBox(
                        width: 50,
                        height: 50,
                        child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                      ),
                    );
                  }

                  var docs = snapshot.data!.docs;

                  return ListView.builder(
                    itemCount: docs.length,
                    reverse: true,
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10),
                    itemBuilder: (context, i) {
                      final data = docs[i].data();


                      // Show two messages - user's prompt and Gemini's response
                      return Column(
                        children: [
                          ChatBubble(
                            isUser: true,
                            text: data['original_prompt'] ?? '',
                          ),
                          ChatBubble(
                            isUser: false,
                            text: data['response'] ?? '',
                            isLoading: data['response'] == null,
                          ),
                        ],
                      );
                    },
                  );
                },
              ),
            ),

            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
              child: TextField(
                controller: messageController,
                decoration: const InputDecoration(
                  border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                  hintText: 'Enter your message and hit Enter',
                ),


                onSubmitted: (String value) {
                  messageController.clear();

                  FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('aura_chat').add({
                    'original_prompt': value,
                    'prompt': "Read $value and return in JSON using these keys: seizure (type, date, duration, symptoms), feelings (date), side_effects (date). If a key it is not existent, return as null",
                    //'response': "You're friends with someone with epilepsy. You are only gonna talk about their epilepsy and answer with comforting or reassuring messages. You can't talk about other things that doesn't involves epilepsy, if your friends try talk about something else, bring back the subject about their epilepsy, asking how is going or how they are feeling",
                    'timestamp': DateTime.now(),
                  });

                },
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

}

I'm using Chatbot with Gemini extension in firebase, so I first tried a work around with the prompt to respond in JSON and than extract the JSON before sending back to the user. But I found out about Gemini Function Calling, but couldn't find examples of extracting, only about using API to use real data in Gemini responses, which it's more complex than what i'm trying to do. I didn't find an easy documentation to work with functions, I started but honestly don't understand lol. I want the chat to flow normally while the data it's extract without the user noticing
